# MediaPlayer error Android Titanium Genymotion

Tags: android, audio, titanium, appcelerator, genymotion

When I press an image I have set up to play a sound I get the following error in console:

```
[WARN] :   AudioSystem: AudioFlinger server died!
[WARN] :   IMediaDeathNotifier: media server died
[ERROR] :  MediaPlayer: error (100, 0)
[ERROR] :  MediaPlayer: Should have subtitle controller already set
[ERROR] :  MediaPlayer: Error (100,0)
[INFO] :   ServiceManager: Waiting for service media.audio_flinger...
[INFO] :   ServiceManager: Waiting for service media.audio_flinger...
[INFO] :   ServiceManager: Waiting for service media.audio_flinger...
[INFO] :   ServiceManager: Waiting for service media.audio_flinger...
[INFO] :   ServiceManager: Waiting for service media.audio_flinger...
[WARN] :   AudioSystem: AudioFlinger not published, waiting...
```

Here is code for the button(image) and sound:

```
var sound = Ti.Media.createSound({
    url: 'sounds/sound.wav'
});

var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image : '/images/ok-button-up.png',
            width : 185,
            height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
            touchEnabled : 'true',
});

image.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    sound.play();
});
```

I am using genymotion emulator (if it matters)

Comment: Does the sound play at all?

Comment: nope. just get the error

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on a Nexus 4 running API version 17 on Genymotion and Titanium SDK 5.4.0. What SDK are you on and what is your target device?

Comment: Titanium SDK 5.3.1.GA target: nexus 5 - 4.4.4 - api 19

Comment: Could you make your wav file available? Have you been able to play any other file?

Comment: I ran it on your specifications just fine. Did you add the ARM Translation and Gapps to your Nexus 5 emulator?

Comment: Sorry went to work, I don't know what those things you mentioned are or how to add them. new to this